# Create a new pgfplotstable that is a subset of another pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I'm using pgfplots to plot a data set, and I want to add a local regression line for a subset of the data. I'm able to calculate the regression line and plot if for the subset, but pgfplots is still using the full data set to calculate the regression line.

I'm also able to print a table containing only the data I want to plot the regression line for. I want to put this subset in a new table, and estimate the regression line on that table, but I can't figure out how. Alternatively, I would like to directly restrict pgfplots to only use the subset to estimate the regression.

Below is a MWE. I first print the subset of data that I want to estimate the regression line on (only two observations in this example). Then I plot the figure I want, but where the regression line is clearly estimated using the full data set.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
    X   Y
    9   8.5555553
    27.5    9.6833334
    45.5    9.015625
    63.5    8.0161295
    81.5    8.6268654
    100 9.9777775
    118.5   10.681818
    136.5   9.5500002
    154.5   10.106061
    172.5   9.8783779
    191 9.8529415
    209.5   10.940298
    227.5   10.075758
    246 10.089552
    263.5   10.526316
    282 11.934066
    300.5   11.708333
    318.5   11.807693
    336.5   11.791667
    355 12.036586
}\datapoints

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  row predicate/.code={
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{X}\of{\datapoints}
    \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotsretval>210 && \pgfplotsretval<250}
    \ifnum \pgfmathresult = 1
      \else \pgfplotstableuserowfalse
    \fi}
]{\datapoints}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot[only marks] table {\datapoints};
            \addplot[restrict x to domain=210:250] table[y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]{\datapoints};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the easiest is to create a new table instead of typesetting and using that macro name for the plotting. Then you can delete that macro by `\pgfplotstableclear{\table}` or whatever your favorite `\relax` method is.

Comment: The typesetting is only there to show that I have the code to pick out the subset I'm after. I want to create a new table containing that data, but I can't figure out how - that's my exactly my question!

If you mean that I could create the new table by hand, then I agree, but what I'm trying to do is create an animation illustrating local linear kernel regression, so I will want to draw many of these pictures where the sample used for the regression line is shifted.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an answer myself, although I'm not quite happy with it. It is possible to write out the restricted data set to disc, then read it in to a new table, and run the regression on the new table. I'm attaching a MWE below. I would prefer if this could be done without having to write to disc, but this solution at least works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
    X   Y
    9   8.5555553
    27.5    9.6833334
    45.5    9.015625
    63.5    8.0161295
    81.5    8.6268654
    100 9.9777775
    118.5   10.681818
    136.5   9.5500002
    154.5   10.106061
    172.5   9.8783779
    191 9.8529415
    209.5   10.940298
    227.5   10.075758
    246 10.089552
    263.5   10.526316
    282 11.934066
    300.5   11.708333
    318.5   11.807693
    336.5   11.791667
    355 12.036586
}\datapoints


\pgfplotstablesave[row predicate/.code={
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{X}\of{\datapoints}
    \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotsretval>210 && \pgfplotsretval<250}
    \ifnum \pgfmathresult = 1
      \else \pgfplotstableuserowfalse
    \fi}]{\datapoints}{temp.dat}

\pgfplotstableread{temp.dat}\datapointstrimmed

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot[only marks] table {\datapoints};
            \addplot[restrict x to domain=210:250] table[x=X,y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]{\datapointstrimmed};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```